# UPDATE Query not working - PHP/MySQL/bind_param

Tags: php, mysql, bindparam

It's a simple update code in a PHP function through a GET call from the front-end(Not sure if this matters), the code is converting a particular time zone value to unix time stamps  -

```
    $oldDate = null;
    $newDate = null;
    $ctr = 0;
    $timeStamp = array();
    $query=  $this->userDatabaseConnection->stmt_init();
    $query->prepare("SELECT Timestamp from Transaction INNER JOIN `Order` ON `Order`.TransactionId = Transaction.TransactionId");
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($tID); //this holds the current time zone values

        while($query->fetch()){

        $oldDate = $tID;

        array_push($timeStamp, $oldDate);
    }

    $query->close();


    foreach($timeStamp as $row){

        $newDate = strtotime($row);


        $queryUpdate= $this->userDatabaseConnection->stmt_init();

        $queryUpdate->prepare("UPDATE `Order` SET OrderDate=? WHERE TransactionId=?");
        error_log("ERROR!",0);

        $queryUpdate->bind_param('is', $unixTS, $oldTS);
        $unixTS = $newDate;
        $oldTS = $row;
        $queryUpdate->execute();
        $queryUpdate->close();

        $ctr++;
    }

    if($ctr == 88){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

The `$ctr` variable is returning the total number of rows that need to be updated - which equals to the correct value and thus returns a true to my front end Angular controller.

I tried echo-ing the `$newDate` and `$row` values - they seem to be correct too.

But it just does not update my table. Can someone please help me figure out why? Am I missing something here? The error log does show the message in my Apache log - but I can't seem to figure out what's causing it.

Comment: Look in your error logs for the actual errors.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP - the apache error log only gives the error message that I've put here and a referrer to my index page from where I am making the call. I'm getting a response as 'true' , so there is something wrong with the execution part?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Your code  is logically incorrect. You select timestamp from transaction table, but then you use this timestamp as an transactionId, which it obviously isn't.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz thanks - there indeed was an issue with the query!